# How to fix: 'TRANS_AMTS_UNBALNCD' when trying to create a Sales Record

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Im trying to create a Sales Order on netsuite, but im getting the fallowing error:

"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"TRANS_AMTS_UNBALNCD","message":"The transaction is not balanced! values ​​+ fees + shipping 0, total value: 90"

Here is the Code:

```
  var salesOrder = record.transform({
    fromType: 'customer',
    fromId: '10807',
    toType: 'salesorder',
    isDynamic: true
  });


  salesOrder.selectNewLine({
    sublistId: 'item'
  });

  salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
    sublistId: 'item',
    fieldId: 'item',
    line: 1,
    value: 1175
  });

  salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
    sublistId: 'item',
    fieldId: 'quantity',
    value: '1'
  });

  salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
    sublistId: 'item',
    fieldId: 'rate',
    value:45
  });

  salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
    sublistId: 'item',
    fieldId: 'amount',
    value: 90
  });

  salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
    sublistId: 'item',
    fieldId: 'taxcode',
    value: 5
  });

  salesOrder.commitLine({ 
    sublistId: 'item'
  });

  salesOrder.save({
    enableSourcing: false,
    ignoreMandatoryFields: true
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

`amount = quantity * rate`

With the code that you're showing, you have one line item with a quantity of 1 and a rate of 45, but the amount you've specified is 90.  You either need to change the amount to 45 or change the quantity to 2, or change the rate to 45.

Or don't specify the amount at all and NetSuite will do the calculation for you.  I usually either specify an amount or a rate but not both.

Comment: I tried to balance as you said but i still getting the same error. Do you have any other ideia why this is happening ?

Comment: I took your code and pasted it into the NetSuite script debugger.  I changed the internal id for the customer, item and tax code to match my environment.  I left the quantity at 1 and the rate at 45.  I changed the amount to 45 (1 * 45) and your code successfully created a sales order in my environment.  As long as your math lines up, your code should work.